# Why is LU decomposition needed to solve linear systems of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I went over some ways to solve systems of linear equations.

The simplest one is by multiplying the coefficient matrix $A$ with elimination matrices in order to get the upper triangular matrix $U$.
An alternative is to do $A=LU$ decomposition.

I went over an example, I understood the solution, but I don't see the point in taking the extra steps of decomposition, looking for inverses, substitution etc etc in order to get the solution for **x**.

Why do we take the extra steps, when the moment we discover the set of elimination matrices, we could just solve for **x** by obtaining the upper triangular matrix $U$? Am I missing something?

Also, not sure if I understood correctly, but $LU$ decomposition works only when we don't have row exchanges?

Comment: The elimination matrices correspond precisely to the matrix $L$. Having the decomposition is very useful when you have to solve multiple linear systems with the same matrix and all the elimination steps are already "coded" in $L$. Regarding your question about row exchanges, you are right, in order to cope with row exchanges you must considrer the factorization $PA = LU$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that it is very simple to solve a linear system $Ax=b$ if $A$ is an upper or lower triangular matrix.

The LU-decomposition is nothing but a modified version of Gauß'-algorithm which you can also use to solve such a linear system. The key feature of LU-decomposition is that if you want to solve finitely many equations $Ax_i=b_i$, then you have to compute LU-decomposition only once to solve all of these equations. If you are using Gauß'-algorithm, you have to perform it over and over again -- once for every equation you want to solve. Thus, since the runtime of both algorithms is $\frac{2}{3}{n^3}$, solving $m$ equations with LU has runtime $\frac{2}{3}n^3+m$, whilst solving $m$ equations with Gauß has runtime $\frac{2}{3}n^3m$ which is much higher.